# DRUPAL 7 - Clean URL and relative path : it's doesn't work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, relative-path, clean-urls

I start with Drupal and I have read some of topics about my problem but I didn't found the solution. 
My problem is the following :

On my website (for the moment in localhost) I use Clean URLS module. The problem is when I enable this module and when I use the relative path of my files, my pictures or links don't work.

For example : src="./sites/default/files/styles/large/public/add_tool_version.png".My pictures are not visibles.. I don't know why this module doesn't work with the relative path.

But when I disable the module, the link is works fine.
Please, can an you help me ? Do you have any solution to fix it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: I test with the path :../sites/default/files/styles/large/public/add_tool_version.png and it works! But now, I don't have the preview the I edit the link. Do you know why? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute paths. In you case with image it would be like:
`src="/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/add_tool_version.png"`, without dot.

This absolute path will always refers to that image instead of relative path - it depends on you current directory or page.

Comment: Without dot it doesn't work. But with 2 dots it works.. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you tell me how looks whole url to image when you use path as i suggested ?

Comment: maybe it can be problem with your base_url in settings.php Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with setting.php file ! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem with clean urls is the way browsers read urls and interpret them as directions in a file directory. Lets say you are at `http://www.example.com/?q=node/11`, or, with clean urls enabled, at `http://www.example.com/node/11`.

When enabeling clean urls, and putting a link with a source into some node, your browser will search for your files in the folder that is specified in your url. Thus, when you declare the source to be `sites/default/files/styles/large/public/add_tool_version.png` and are on the url `http://www.example.com/node/11`, then the browser will look for the file in the directory `node/11/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/`. Usually this would work, but in drupal, there actually is no such folder. All drupal pages are just versions of the index.php in your base-directory. In drupal, the url doesn't have anything to do with file structure - unfortunately, the average browser doesn't know that.

Without clean urls, however, your browser will *recognize* the url as a combination of a base path (`www.example.com`) and a query (`?q=node/11`). It will therefore look for your file starting from the directory specified in your base path.

If you still want to have your relative paths working with clean urls enabled, you can use the function `base_path()` in front of your actual source.

Comment: NB: So browser sometimes get confused when finding links on a drupal site leading to a path they cannot recognize. Note that this has nothing to do with how drupal handles urls internally: drupal will read in and process any url correctly as a combination of a base-path and a query and display the appropriate content. Only when that content itself contains some links problems can occur: after having correctly delivered the page's html including the link, drupal leaves it's hands off the page to let the browser do the actual lookup of the link's source.